# How do I set a plane to not fall?

Tags: animation, physics

I've been trying to set up a physics simulation so I can drop an Ico mesh on top of a plane and then collide they collide. However, I can't get the plane to stay in place, it just starts falling down with the Ico. It would be great if somebody could give me steps for how to keep the plane in place. I am relatively new to blender so sorry if I did not give you enough info. Thank you.

Comment: Make the plane a passive rigid body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have set the plane to **Rigid Body** in the **Physics Tab**.

In the **Physics Tab**, change its **Type** from **Active** to **Passive**.

Voila!  The plane will not fall.

Add **Collision** to the sphere to stop it falling through the plane.  In 2.8x, this will happen without having to add Collision.

Answer (score 2):

Change the ground plane's *Rigid Body Type* to *Passive*

[image]

Comment: If they're colliding at high speeds, the physics can get glitchy and objects can pass through each other. Try adding a bit of depth to the plane.